# Missing number treated as zero -- but why?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm making my references page, and this is my first entry:

Asch, Solomon E. 1955. “Opinions and Social Pressure.” Scientific American 193 (November): 31--35.

I'm getting the following error message:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>   
>   \par
>   l.308 As
>   ch, Solomon E. 1955. “Opinions and Social Pressure.” Scientific ...
>   A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

This causes an unending loop of errors until Tex stops itself. I'm not sure where it's expecting a number, or how to prevent it from missing one.

EDIT:

I'm not using a constructed bibliography. I've manually made a references page, using `\begin{hangparas}` to format, and am inserting that specific line for my entries.

```
\newpage

\begin{center} 
  \Large{References}
\end{center}

\begin{hangparas}
Asch, Solomon E. 1955. “Opinions and Social Pressure.” Scientific American 193 (November): 31--35.
\end{hangparas}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hanparas` environment (from `hanging` package) requires two additional arguments:

```
\begin{hangparas}{<indent>}{<afternum>}
  ...
\end{hangparas}
```

where *indent* specifies the amount of indentation (e.g., 1in) and *afternum* (e.g., 2) controls the lines that will be indented.

The *afternum* argument can be a positive or negative value. For example, *afternum = 2* means that the lines after the 2nd line will be indented; and *afternum = -2* means the first 2 lines will be indented.